# Accuracy for every class in Weka

Tags: class, classification, precision, weka

Normally Weka provides the final whole correct and incorrect accuracy for the applied data set.

Is there a way to view the accuracy for every class individually?

Answer (score 1):

"Detailed Accuracy By Class" gives what you want. For details see [How to interpret weka classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903933/how-to-interpret-weka-classification)